# Unable to create Import Jobs in Information governance of Microsoft 365 compliance in Exchange Online

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

We r using Microsoft 365. I am trying to create Import Jobs in Information governance of  Microsoft 365 compliance in Exchange Online. I am getting the message "To create import jobs, you must be assigned the Mailbox Import Export role in Exchange Online. After this role is assigned, it might take up to 24 hours before you can start creating jobs."

I have assigned myself the "Global Administrator" Role. In EAC > Admin Roles, I have assigned myself to "Organization Management". To the same "Organization Management" role, the permission "Mailbox Import Export" has been assigned. 3 days have passed since I assigned the roles.

Why am I not able to import yet?

Comment: Did you use this global administrator account to access compliance center? Try to access EAC in incognito mode and assign this Mailbox Import Export role again, and see if there is any difference after a while.

Comment: I am using the same account with global administrator to access the compliance center. I have checked again. I have logged in to EAC in incognito and have removed the user from the Organisation Management role. then reassigned. Will wait and try ....

Comment: Interestingly, the Classic Exchange admin center Does NOT show the 'Mailbox Import Export role ' assigned to the 'Organisation Management' role group but the new version shows it as assigned!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the Classic Exchange admin center Does NOT show the 'Mailbox Import Export role ' assigned to the 'Organization Management' role group but the new version shows it as assigned!!!

After **I assigned the permission to the role using the classical admin center**, it works immediately!

Comment: I'm glad that you've fixed this role issue. If there is a similar issue, feel free to post it. If everything works well, you could mark the solution as the best answer to finish this thread. Have a good day!